# How to combine LINQ and Lambda?

Tags: linq, lambda

How do I combine these two?

```
var viewModel2 = tu.SingleOrDefault(su => su.email == logindetails.Email);




//Get jobs and personal details
var viewModel = from u in db.badusers
                            join r in db.Users on u.email equals r.Email
                            join j in db.roles on u.id equals j.roleid
                            where r.UserName.Equals(usernameCookie)
                            select new JoinedModel { roles = u, jobs = j, users = r};
```

Should my select come after?

Notes:
JoinedModel contains multiple models. If I try to return viewModel2 the data is correct however it's a View with multiple models hence why I have to use ViewModel ( JoinedModel ) so the the error thrown is the standard 'I expected JoinedModel (viewModel ) but your passing me viewModel2.'

Comment: We need more details. What type is `tu`? What is your expected result? What have you tried already?

Comment: I have added more details.

Comment: Still not clear where `viewmodel2` is supposed to be used. Are you trying to return two objects? Is the return type a tuple, or does the `JoinedModel` have a constructor taking those two objects?

Comment: Return type is this @model IEnumerable<theclient.Models.JoinedModel>. I think the main thing I am trying to get across here is I can have any number of these LINQ queries .SingleOrDefault(su => su.email == logindetails.Email); ,.SingleOrDefault(su => su.surname == logindetails.surname); etc but my View has to have returned this model JoinedModel because I have multiple sections each outputting a different model on this View.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an **anonymous object**, although I'd strongly suggest to choose more descriptive item names:

```
var combinedModel = new {
    viewModel2 = tu.SingleOrDefault(su => su.email == logindetails.Email),
    viewModel = from u in db.badusers
                join r in db.Users on u.email equals r.Email
                join j in db.roles on u.id equals j.roleid
                where r.UserName.Equals(usernameCookie)
                select new JoinedModel { roles = u, jobs = j, users = r}
};
```

This will create an object `combinedModel`, with two properties: `combinedModel.viewModel2` and `combinedModel.viewModel`.

Comment: This may work if tweaked, right now it's giving me: An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Core.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Sequence contains more than one matching element

Comment: Will enable my try catches to see if any SQL is even returned.

Comment: The error `Sequence contains more than one matching element` is probably caused by the `SingleOrDefault()` call. It found multiple items which is illegal when using `SingleOrDefault()`, it basically means "give me the single item that exists, or null if not found, or throw an Exception if there is more than 1 item". You can try `FirstOrDefault()` if you don't care about multiple existing items and you just want any one of them.